# leaflet integrates maplibre-gl @maplibre/maplibre-gl-leaflet

Tags: angular, webpack, maplibre-gl

I am not very familiar with webpack 1.15.0 version,so please help me
projects use
angular 1.5.8
webpack 1.15.0
babel-* 6.x
leaflet 1.7.1
I want to integrate a maplibre-gl map layer on a leafet layer so that this layer can directly use the events I have written in leafet.
I am install maplibre-gl 3.3.0 and @maplibre/maplibre-gl-leaflet 0.0.19
when i was write this code require('@maplibre/maplibre-gl-leaflet') (I need maplibreGL to be imported from this library )
it will show webpack error
webpack_loader.exceptions.WebpackError:
ModuleParseError in
Module parse failed: D:\Project\app\source\node_modules\maplibre-gl\dist\maplibre-gl.js Unexpected token (31:119689)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I tried to lower the @ maplibre/maplibre-gl-leaflet version.
Add ts-loader to webpack